# I get how many data from my firebase but there's no output

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

There's no error in my code. I get the size of how many data that are store in it but there are no productName, productCode, etc output in the RecyclerView. I don't know and I already tried my best and still no progress. I just wanted to show the data which will be set inside the cardview. So here's the problem. [FirebaseDatabase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqkzS.png) as you can see I have 5 data inside my Product. Then I want to show the detail of it like code, expireDate, and name. In this case I'm testing only outputting code and name only. And when I run it, the output is like this[VirtualAndroidDevice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzSSb.png) as you can see I get how many data which is 5 but there should be a 2 textView that contains the code and name.

ProductAdapter.kt

```
class ProductAdapter(options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product>) : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Product, ProductAdapter.ViewHolder>(options) {

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

        val productCode:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.productCodeTextView)
        val productName:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.NUPTextView)

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val layout:View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_product, parent, false)

        return ViewHolder(layout)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, model: Product) {
        holder.productName.setText(model.getProductName())
        holder.productCode.setText(model.getProductCode())
    }
}
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
        recyclerView = layout.findViewById(R.id.homeFragmentRecyclerView)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        val query: Query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()

        val options: FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Product> = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Product>()
            .setQuery(query, Product::class.java)
            .build()

        adapter = ProductAdapter(options)
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        return layout
    }
```

Product.kt

```
private var code: String? = null
    private var name: String? = null

    fun Product(code: String?, name: String?) {
        this.code = code
        this.name = name
    }

    fun getProductCode(): String? {
        return code
    }

    fun setProductCode(code: String?) {
        this.code = code
    }

    fun getProductName(): String? {
        return name
    }

    fun setProductName(name: String?) {
        this.name = name
    }
```

For anyone asking for item_product.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFE8">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/productCodeTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product Code"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/NUPTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="NUP"
            android:layout_below="@id/productCodeTextView"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: There's not much we can do without seeing the data that you expect to appear.  Please edit the question to show your data, and describe in more detail what you expect this code to do with it.

Comment: @DougStevenson I already update it. Sorry

Comment: @MohammadAzriKhairuddin Can you show the xml of item_product